# After sending email from this php code, footer not showing it dissapears why?

Tags: php

*"this whole code of this php is in footer.php file"
"footer is showing before submitting!"
"footer is not showing after submitting!"*

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
    {
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];  }$to = "someone@example.com";  $subject = "";  $message = ""; $headers = "From: " .$email;  if (isset($_POST["Submit"]) && (!empty($email)))
    {
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  if ($success){
    echo "<script>alert('Subscription Done! Please Stay tuned.')</script>";  }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Email for Newsletter subscription was not successful.')</script>";  }
die();
    }     ?>
```

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: it was not uploading so i took screen shot

Comment: It __does__,  and you need to read formating rules.

Comment: I didnt understood it. i pasted php code. it says correct the format!

Comment: When you post the question, there's a large yellow box on the right side of the screen with the title "How to Format". Read it.

Comment: can i do this? !mail($to, $subject, $message);

Comment: pasted now tell me

Comment: tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this edited code

```
$from = "Danial@example.com";
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Hi,";
$message = "This mail is testing mail by $from";
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && (!empty($email)))
{
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129143/discussion-on-answer-by-vijaya-vignesh-kumar-after-sending-email-from-this-php-c).

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: i cant chat there